Numerically stable analog of the $x\cdot y=\exp(\ln(x)+\ln(y))$ formula
Numerically stable analog of the $x\cdot y=\exp(\ln(x)+\ln(y))$ formula.
The aforementioned formula expresses a binary multiplication via binary addition and single-parameter functions.
However the formula does not work well in numerical applications when $x$ and $y$ are around $0$ since logarithm is not defined for $x\le0$ and tends to negative infinity near $0$. So, I'd like to have an analogous formula that's more numerically stable.
I'd like to find two 1-parameter functions $f$ and $g$ such that $g(f(x)+f(y))=x\cdot y$.
Is $f=\ln, g=\exp$ the only solution?
I briefly thought to use the fact that $x\cdot y=(x^{-1} * y^{-1})^{-1}$, but that does not improve anything since $|\ln(x)|=|\ln(x^{-1})|$.
I though about trying to extract $x\cdot y$ from a sum that's more stable around $0$: $\ln(x+k)+\ln(y+k)$, but that seems infeasible.
I'd like to explore possible solutions in the following spaces:

$x$, $y$ are real
$x$, $y$ are real and finite (e.g. $|x|<1$)
$x$, $y$ are fixed-point $n$-bit numbers
$x$, $y$ are floating-point numbers

Background: I'm exploring the feasibility of approximating functions of many parameters with a rich set of single-parameter functions and a very small set of binary operations (ideally just a single operation: addition). The system will be used with floating point numbers, so it needs to be somewhat numerically stable.
The first obvious problem to overcome is how to express the multiplication operation via 1-parameter functions and addition.
Update:
I'm thinking further about the mapping between $f(x) + f(y)$ and $x \cdot y$. It seems to me that every value of $f(x) + f(y)$ needs to map to a unique value of $x \cdot y$.
Strict bijection does not seem to be required it is highly likely.
In case of bijection it's likely $f$ would need to satisfy the following property to be a feasible candidate: $f(x) + f(y)$ needs to be constant along every $x \cdot y = p$ curve.
So $f(x) + f(p/x)$ needs to be constant.
Differentiating, we get $f'(x) - f'(p/x) \cdot p /x^2 = 0$
One solution to this equation is $f'(x) = a/x$ which corresponds to $f(x) = a \cdot ln(x) + C$. Could there be other solutions?

$$x \cdot y=(x+10)(y+10)-(10)(x+y)-100=\exp(\ln(x+10)+\ln(y+10))-10(x+y)-100$$ I know this is a little ugly (and of course $10$ is arbitrary) but does this work? Apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Before the invention of the logarithm table, trigonometric identities with cosine and sine tables were used. Of course one has to first scale the factors by powers of 10 so that the remaining factors are smaller than 1.

@Malady I had this idea too, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The first term is good, however the problem is that the $(x+y)$ term cannot be calculated from just $s=\ln(x+10)+\ln(y+10)$. And in general I suspect that there is no bijection between such $s$ and $x \cdot y$.

@LutzLehmann Trigonometric identities sound interesting. I've looked a bit, but I'm not sure how to do it. We need to calculate $trig_g(x \cdot y)$ from $trig_f(x)$ and  $trig_f(y)$. And I cannot find a clear path. It feels like trying to calculate $\exp(i \cdot x \cdot y)$ from $\exp(i \cdot x)$ and $\exp(i \cdot y)$.

You use $2\cos(A)\cos(B)=\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)$ to transform a multiplication into additions. How one prepares the arguments is a form of art, to stay in regions where the function table has the best resolution.

@LutzLehmann I've tried that a bit (as well as going from the other direction like $\sin(x)+\sin(y) = 2 \cdot \sin(x/2+y/2) \cdot \cos(x/2-y/2)$). However I'm not sure I'm getting anywhere. Notice that $\cos(A+B)$ is a function of 2 parameters rather than one. For this to work the right side would need to have the following form: $f1(A) + f2(B)$

Short answer:
For real numbers it looks like logarithm-based solution is the only feasible solution to the problem.
For integers and fixed-point numbers alternative solutions might exist, but they are likely to lead to significant precision/data loss.
Full answer:
Let's think about the mapping between $f(x) + f(y)$ and $x \cdot y$. It seems to me that every value of $f(x) + f(y)$ needs to map to a unique value of $x \cdot y$.
If this mapping is bijection:
(I think it also applies if the mapping has finite multiplicity.)
In case of bijection $f$ needs to satisfy the following property to be a feasible candidate: $f(x) + f(y)$ needs to be constant along every $x \cdot y = p$ curve.
So $f(x) + f(p/x)$ needs to be constant.
Differentiating, we get $f'(x) - f'(p/x) \cdot p /x^2 = 0$
One solution to this equation is $f'(x) = a/x$ which corresponds to $f(x) = a \cdot ln(x) + C$. It seems to me there are no other solutions to that equation.
If the mapping is not a bijection:
If the mapping has finite multiplicity it seems to me that the bijection case still applies. So it looks like the only remaining case is completely non-continuous mapping.
A mapping that's non-continuous everywhere:
In case where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers the non-continuous mapping is an interesting case, but is likely not a feasible solution for the original problem.
For discrete numbers (e.g. fixed point numbers) there is still a possibility for discrete functions that implement the non-continuous mapping. However the addition operation still poses a problem since it mixes the operand data in hard to recover way. There is a dedicated question about this: Restoring the set of $x$ and $y$ from the result of addition: $s = f(x) + f(y)$
